# Weird Logon Issue

Tags: login-screen

I have this weird issue with Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS M1530 in which Ubuntu boots, makes a noise when the prompt shows up, and when I type the correct password, it freezes on the login wallpaper with the watermark, “Ubuntu 16.04 LTS”

Why does it do this and how do I fix it?

This happened after I tried to disable a driver in the “Additional Drivers” menu.